# Running Node Lambdas and C# Lambdas on AWS Simultaneously

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm very new to using lambdas, but I've now got to maintain a large collection of them written in .NET 2.1. For numerous reasons I would prefer to use node instead going forward. The .NET lambdas cannot be refactored to node in a reasonable timeframe so it would be necessary for them to run alongside one another. Is this possible without significant configuration?

I don't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't work out of the box. Looks like I can just create a new lambda function and specify that it should be node. However, I'm so new to lambdas and am dealing with production code, so I want to be certain I won't break something by doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lambda was designed to work like you'd expect. You can have many running in different languages, and they are unrelated to each other and will run in parallel.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that specifically said this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different lambda functions are **separate** from each other and don't share information or code by default (you can use Lambda Layers to explicitly do that).

This means from a technical perspective there is nothing stopping you from mixing any of the [supported runtimes / execution contexts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) in **different** lambda functions.

Creating new node-based lambdas and migrating the code from the .net core lambdas over a longer period of time is a suitable migration strategy.

You can also change the runtime of an existing lambda function, this means if you've got hard-coded or difficult to change dependencies on your existing .net lambdas, you can update the code to javascript and then switch the runtime to some version of node. This makes it possible to keep the ARN and name of the lambda function static in case that's a requirement.